# How to use gradle-izpack plugin with izpack 5.0.0

Tags: gradle, izpack

We are using gradle-izpack for a while now, and it works pretty well.
I tried to upgrade the dependency to izpack 5.0.0-rc1, downloaded from distribution site.
Anyhow, I'm facing a strange error when packing the installer:

```
:izPackCreateInstaller
[ant:izpack] Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException: componentInstance cannot be null
[ant:izpack]    at org.picocontainer.adapters.InstanceAdapter.getInstanceClass(InstanceAdapter.java:69)
[ant:izpack]    at org.picocontainer.adapters.InstanceAdapter.<init>(InstanceAdapter.java:50)
[ant:izpack]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addConfig(DefaultPicoContainer.java:506)
[ant:izpack]    at com.izforge.izpack.core.container.AbstractContainer.addConfig(AbstractContainer.java:172)
[ant:izpack]    at com.izforge.izpack.ant.IzpackAntRunnable.run(IzpackAntRunnable.java:43)
[ant:izpack]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I found a similar post from one year ago, but no solution.

Any help is appreciated
Jürgen

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this.  I ended up having to call the compiler directly.

```
configurations {
   izpack    
}

dependencies {
    izpack 'org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-ant:5.0.0-rc4'
    izpack project(':symmetric-pro-izpack')
}

task izpack(dependsOn:'prepareIzpack') {
    description = "Creates an IzPack based installer for both binary and source distributions."

    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = 'com.izforge.izpack.compiler.bootstrap.CompilerLauncher'
            classpath = configurations.izpack
            args = [
                "$projectDir/src/izpack/install.xml",
                "-b",
                "$buildDir/assemble/izpack",
                "-o",
                "$buildDir/distributions/app-${version}-setup.jar",
                "-c",
                "deflate",
                "-l",
                "9",
                "-k",
                "standard"                    
            ]
        }
    }
}
```